# getchar not working as I would expect as loop control variable

Tags: c, getchar

Working my way through K&R and having a hard time understanding the behavior of getchar.
Consider the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
        int c;

        while (( c = getchar()) != EOF)
        {
                putchar(c);
        }
}
```

I would expect this program to output each character as I type it, but instead the loop only executes after a newline has been entered. Does getchar not return until a newline is entered?

Thank you in advance for any explanation

Comment: OT, return type of `main()` should be `int`.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Thanks for posting a complete minimal example. That can make it much easier to answer questions.